# How can I read xml file inside war? - maven

Tags: java, maven

I am creating a war through pom.xml (maven java application). I want to read xml file residing inside war file. How can i do this?

xml file location before build:

> C:\PrivateProjects\CancerEHR\src\main\resources\Configuration.xml

xml file location after running pom.xml

> C:\PrivateProjects\CancerEHR\target\classes\main\resources\Configuration.xml

Comment: @jcalloway I am getting input stream null with your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
InputStream inputStream = 
      getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/resources/Configuration.xml");
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream ))
```